# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I'm attempting to integrate jquery's datepicker with formtastic as detailed [here](http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/ruby-on-rails-formtastic-jquery-ui-datepicker)

I've followed the directions exactly, but am getting "uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions" when running this code:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @item, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'form'} do |f| %>
 <div class="group">
  <%= f.label :create_date, :class => 'label' %>
  <%= f.input :create_date, :as => :datepicker %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I attempted to put this in my config/application.rb:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/conversions'
```

I've restarted the server but am still getting the same error. Am I putting this require line in the correct place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking the page you linked, I assume the problem is the following line:

```
format = options[:format] || ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS[:default] || '%d %b %Y'
```

Looking at the [file you mentioned](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb), it appears that Rails now modifies the `Date` class directly rather than defining `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date`; furthermore, passing `:default` as the key to `DATE_FORMATS` appears to just call `to_default_s` on the object. The easiest way to deal with this would probably be to remove the whole reference to `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions`, since the code also specifies a default:

```
format = options[:format] || '%d %b %Y'
```

You could also specify one of the date formats Rails adds in `conversions.rb` as so:

```
format = options[:format] || Date::DATE_FORMATS[:rfc822] || '%d %b %Y'
```