# datepicker jquery ui and rails 3(.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi i am using the date picker jquery ui in combination with rails 3.1. The date picker looks brilliant, only the date isn't stored in the database? Only sometimes...? So that's a difficult error.

This is my .js file:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#question_deadline").datepicker({ duration: 'fast', maxDate: '+2m', minDate: 'now', showOn: "button", buttonImage: "calendar.gif", buttonImageOnly: true });
    $("#question_deadline").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "drop");
    $("#question_deadline").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy"); 
});
```

In my controller there's just plain rails script:

```
def create    
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])


    if @question.save
      redirect_to questions_path, :notice => "Successfully created question."
    else
      setup_questions
      render :index
    end
  end
```

In views file _form.html.erb i use a text_field to display the date:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content, :placeholder => "type your question here.." %>
    <%= f.text_field :deadline %><br /> 
  </div>
```

Are there people who have experience with datepiacker jquery ui and rails, the ryan bates episode, didn't solve it, i think that was written in rails 2.3?

Regards,
Thijs

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Well, when i select a date the date appears in the textfield, but when i try to save the form all fields are saved into the database exept the date field?? And the date field is available in the table...? And the strange thing is that is sometimes do saves it... But more often 'no save' than a save

Comment: It doesn't sound like a problem with datepicker... Have you checked the requests and see whether `deadline` is being sent?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to show us the view where you have the datepicker element. If it's like this:

```
<input type="text" name="question_deadline" id="question_deadline" />
```

When you submit this form, the parameters you receive in your controller (in the method "create") is called question_deadline. So in that create method you should first write:

```
if params[:question_deadline] != ""
    params[:question][:question_deadline] = params[:question_deadline]
end
#add a else if this date field is compulsory in the database
```

This step is important because the create method will read stuff from params[:question][:question_deadline] not from params[:question_deadline] which is returned from the view.
Thus params[:question][:question_deadline] is empty when you do @question.save

To display the date, you also need to show us the controller "show" method that should be something like:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id]) #or any sql request that returns info about a question.
```

Then in the view you can retrieve it simply with:

```
<%= @question.question_deadline%>
```

Maybe with more code from you controller and view I can elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

I think, Rails/Ruby is not able to parse a date in this format:

```js
$("#question_deadline").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy");
// full day name, day (w/o leading zero), full month name, 4-digit year
```

In your controller, you might want to add a line such as

```ruby
def create/update
  ...
  @question.deadline = DateTime.strptime(params[:question][:deadline], '%A, %d %B, %Y')
  # assuming my jquery-to-ruby format-mapping is adequate ;-)
  if @question.save
    ...
end
```

Beware, that this code easily breaks on malformed date strings.

If you don't want to change the format to, e.g. `'yy-mm-dd'` (in Ruby-land it's `'%Y-%m-%d'`), you may want to populate the selected date to another HTML element using the [`altField` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat) and hide the actual datepicker input field via CSS:

```js
$("#somewhere_else").datepicker(
  dateFormat: "%yy-%mm-%dd",
  altField:   "#question_deadline",
  altFormat:  "DD, d MM, yy",
  ...
);
```

```html
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= text_field_tag 'somewhere_else', @question.deadline %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :deadline %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

That'll work, at least for me :-)

—Dominik

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to update the way ActiveSupport parses dates. This is outlined in [Default Date Format in Rails (Need it to be ddmmyyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610485/default-date-format-in-rails-need-it-to-be-ddmmyyyy)