# rails db won't save string as date with m/d/y format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date

saving a string to my db as a date and having some strange results

if the date is formatted like,

dd/mm/yy it will save

if date is formatted like,

mm/dd/yy it will fail to save silently

in my console if i go

```
'20/10/2012'.to_date 
 => Sat, 20 Oct 2012
```

it works

if i go

```
'10/20/2012'.to_date
=> ArgumentError: invalid date ...
```

it breaks

i used an initializer to set up my default date format to %m/%d/%Y which you can see is accurately reflected in my DATE_FORMATS hash.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS
=> {:short=>"%e %b", :long=>"%B %e, %Y", :db=>"%Y-%m-%d", :number=>"%Y%m%d", :long_ordinal=>#<Proc:0x007f8663f1aae0@/Users/ian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb:12 (lambda)>, :rfc822=>"%e %b %Y", :default=>"%m/%d/%Y"}
```

Uncertain what is the cause of the issue here, as things seem to be configured correctly. How to resolve?

thank you!

Comment: This link might be relevant to your problem.


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610485/default-date-format-in-rails-need-it-to-be-ddmmyyyy

Comment: @istan Did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
DateTime.strptime('20/10/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Or just use Date if you don't need an associated time:

```
Date.strptime('20/10/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: i need a general solution so i dont need to call strptime every time a form is passing a date string to a controller (happens a lot in this app)

Answer (score 2):

Use gem [american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date)

In gem file 
gem 'american_date'

Now it will save mm/dd/yyyy date format.