# How to change date format from yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

```
<div class="field2">
<%= f.label :shod_date, "Date of last shoeing" %><br />
<%= f.date_select :shod_date %>
```

Can someone please just tell me what codes to add and where i should add them. Also which commands i should run. Plus i want the initial year to date back further than 2007 because the start year starts at 2007 and ends at 2012

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default Date Format in Rails (Need it to be ddmmyyyy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610485/default-date-format-in-rails-need-it-to-be-ddmmyyyy)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= f.date_select :shod_date,
    use_month_numbers: true,
    order: [:day, :month, :year],
    start_year: 2007,
    date_separator: "/" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

use      shod_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

Comment: Yeah. Downvoting should always be explained!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **date format** using [internationalisation (I18n)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Just add (or change) this in your `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  date:
    order:
      - :day
      - :month
      - :year
```

Note that this example is for english (`en`) locale, and you should replace `en` for your language.

Using i18n, all your `date_select` will be setted with this format. If you want change the order only in this point, use the attribute `order: [:day, :month, :year]` as @hirata-yasuyuki sugested.

To display only years between 2007 and current you can set two attributes: **`start_year`** and **`end_year`** to `date_select` helper.

And your code show looks like:

```
<%= f.date_select :shod_date, start_year: 2007, end_year: Time.now.year %>
```